# Select OK button from N'th modal opened in testcafe

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I open two modals in my testing, and I want to be able to click on the "OK" button in the second modal (the second selected element in the below html).

My current code is :

```
import { waitForReact } from 'testcafe-react-selectors';
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `App tests`
    .page('http://localhost:3000/')
    .beforeEach(async () => {
        await waitForReact();
    });

test('Can open and accept all pop ups', async t => {

    //open first modal
    await t
        .click('#LayerAddingPopUpButtonID');

    //select OK button from first modal
    const modalOKButton = Selector('div.ant-modal')
        .find('div.ant-modal-footer')
        .find('button.ant-btn-primary');

    //click OK button from first modal
    await t
        .expect(modalOKButton.with({visibilityCheck: true}).exists)
        .ok({timeout: 30000})
        .hover(modalOKButton)
        .click(modalOKButton);

    //open second modal
    await t
        .click('#LayerDeletingPopUpButtonID');

    //select OK button from second modal
    const secondModalOKButton = Selector(??);
});
```

The html I'm working with is the following. I'm trying to select the second OK button:

[image]

Comment: how do you open second modal ?
does your second click opens second modal ?

Comment: That's right, the click on #LayerDeletingPopUpButtonID causes the second opened modal to be rendered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you try using `nth` ?

```
const modalOKButton = Selector('div.ant-modal').nth(1)
        .find('div.ant-modal-footer')
        .find('button.ant-btn-primary');
```

or maybe try using selector by `aria-labelledby`

```
const modalOKButton = Selector("[aria-labelledby='rcDialogTitle1']")
        .find('div.ant-modal-footer')
        .find('button.ant-btn-primary');
```